# get emacs 23 buffer-list behavior in emacs 24?

Tags: macos, emacs

I just upgraded emacs from 23.4 to 24.1 (on OS X).  I use [emacs-starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit), but it doesn't appear to affect this behavior in 24.1 (I have it disabled at the moment), and I'm pretty sure I got my expected behavior in 23 before I started using it.

In 23.4 if I had buffer "x" open and opened up file "y", the buffer-list showed "y" before "x", meaning

- while in buffer "x" <kbd>C-x <left></kbd> (`previous-buffer`) switched to buffer "y"
- while in buffer "y" <kbd>C-x <right></kbd> (`next-buffer`)switched to buffer "x"

This order would get changed when I used <kbd>C-x b</kbd>, but I was ok with that.

In 24.1 opening a file seems to sometimes reorder the buffer list and sometimes add the file after the current buffer in the buffer list (depending on the number of files open and the position of the current buffer when I ran <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> to open the other file).  Neither behavior is expected by me.  How can I get the 23.4 (and earlier) behavior back?

I know this seems minor, but I've trained myself over the past several years to expect a specific behavior from <kbd>C-x <left></kbd> and <kbd>C-x <right></kbd> and the new behavior is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`setq Buffer-menu-sort-column nil`

If you work with multiple frames, the default setting is for buffers never selected in a particular frame to be listed at the end. Change that with this

`setq Buffer-menu-user-frame-buffer-list nil` (default is **t**)

Comment: This isn't the exact behavior I want, but it's much closer, and I should be able to get it from here.  Thanks.

Comment: In that case, [buffer-menu-plus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuPlus) offers a new column for display and sort called `Time` which is the time that a buffer was last accessed (displayed).